# Animate pyqtgraph in class

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to write a program that gets serial data from an arduino, via serial, and plots it in real time. I wrote code using matplotlib but I want happy with the results so I am trying to get it to work on pyqtgraph (there are much fewer resources to learn how to use it). my problem is that the code shows an empty graph. it seems _update is being called just once, but when I put it in a loop the graph doesn't even show.

I've written some other code that does what I want, which is plot the data in real time and after the data passes a threshold it plots new lines over the data showing a linear regression. I got an example from here (https://github.com/JaFeKl/joystick_real_time_plot_with_pyqtgraph/blob/master/real_time_plot.py) because I wanted my code to be callable (in a function, but I can't get it to work. so far I'm generating data from within python to simplify debugging

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

import serial

# test
import math
import time


class Graph(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(parent)
        self.n = 3
        self.mainbox = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainbox)
        self.mainbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.canvas = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()             # create GrpahicsLayoutWidget obejct  
        self.mainbox.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

        #  Set up plot
        self.analogPlot = self.canvas.addPlot(title='Signal from serial port')
        self.analogPlot.setYRange(-1,1123)                # set axis range
        self.analogPlot.setXRange(-1,1123)
        self.analogPlot.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.5) # show Grid
        x_axis = self.analogPlot.getAxis('bottom')
        y_axis = self.analogPlot.getAxis('left')
        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(20)
        x_axis.tickFont = font
        y_axis.tickFont = font
        x_axis.setLabel(text='Tensão [V]')              # set axis labels
        y_axis.setLabel(text='Corrente [mA]')

        self.plts = []
        self.intplts = []
        colors = ['r', 'b', 'w', 'y', 'g', 'm', 'c', 'k']
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.plts.append([])
            self.intplts.append([])


        for i in range(self.n):
            if len(self.plts) <= len(colors):
                self.plts[i]=(self.analogPlot.plot(pen= pg.mkPen(colors[i], width=6)))
        for i in range(self.n):
            if len(self.plts) <= len(colors)*2:
                self.intplts.append(self.analogPlot.plot(pen= pg.mkPen(colors[i+3], width=3)))

        #Data
        self.datay = []
        self.datax = []
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.datax.append([])
            self.datay.append([])

        # set up image exporter (necessary to be able to export images)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
        self.exporter=pg.exporters.ImageExporter(self.canvas.scene())
        self.image_counter = 1


        # start updating
        self.t=0

        self._update()


    def _update(self):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if self.t<= 30:
            #line = raw.readline()
            #data.append(int(line))
            self.datay[0].append(math.sin(self.t+(math.pi/2)))
            self.datay[1].append(math.sin(self.t+(5*math.pi/4)))
            self.datay[2].append(math.sin(self.t))
            self.datax[0].append(self.t)
            self.datax[1].append(self.t)
            self.datax[2].append(self.t)
            self.t+=0.1
            self.plts[0].setData(self.datax[0], self.datay[0])
            self.plts[1].setData(self.datax[1], self.datay[1])
            self.plts[2].setData(self.datax[2], self.datay[2])

            app.processEvents()
        elif self.t>=30 and self.t<=30.1 :
            self.t+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot = Graph()
    plot.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect results similar to this code( only without the linear regression)

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

# linear regression
from scipy import stats

#Arduino
#import find_arduino
#import find_buad
import serial

import math
import time

#port = find_arduino.FindArduino()
#baud = find_buad.FindBaudRate()
ard=None

def Con():
    global ard
    ard = serial.Serial(port,baud,timeout=5)
    time.sleep(2) # wait for Arduino
    ard.close()

# define the data
theTitle = "pyqtgraph plot"
datay = [[],[],[]]
datax = [[],[],[]]
x2 = []
T=[]
t=0

y1L=[]
x1L=[]

# create plot
### START QtApp #####
app = QtGui.QApplication([])            # you MUST do this once (initialize things)
####################
win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Signal from serial port") # creates a window
plt = win.addPlot(title="Realtime plot")  # creates empty space for the plot in the window

font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(20)
plt.getAxis("bottom").tickFont = font
plt.getAxis("left").tickFont = font

plt1 = plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('r', width=6))
plt2= plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('b', width=6))
plt3= plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('w', width=6))

plt1I = plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('y', width=3))
plt2I = plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('g', width=3))
plt3I = plt.plot(pen=pg.mkPen('m', width=3))

plt.showGrid(x=True,y=True)


def update():
    global plt1,plt2,plt3, t, plt1I, plt2I, plt3I
    if t<= 30:
        #line = raw.readline()
        #data.append(int(line))
        datay[0].append(math.sin(t+(math.pi/2)))
        datay[1].append(math.sin(t+(5*math.pi/4)))
        datay[2].append(math.sin(t))
        datax[0].append(t)
        datax[1].append(t)
        datax[2].append(t)
        t+=0.1
        plt1.setData(datax[0],datay[0])
        plt2.setData(datax[1],datay[1])
        plt3.setData(datax[2],datay[2])
        app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(0.01)
    elif t>=30 and t<=30.1 :
        #plt1I.setData([0,1,2],[5,3,1])
        #app.processEvents()
        interp(plt1I, plt2I, plt3I)
        t+=1
    else:
        app.processEvents()

def interp(pt1, pt2, pt3):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(datax[0][10:],datay[0][10:])
    x=[]
    y=[]
    print(slope)
    for i in datax[0][10:]:
        x.append(i)
        y.append(intercept+slope*i)
    pt1.setData(x,y)

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(datax[1][10:],datay[1][10:])
    x=[]
    y=[]
    print(slope)
    for i in datax[0][10:]:
        x.append(i)
        y.append(intercept+slope*i)
    pt2.setData(x, y)

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(datax[2][10:],datay[2][10:])
    x=[]
    y=[]
    print(slope)
    for i in datax[0][10:]:
        x.append(i)
        y.append(intercept+slope*i)
    pt3.setData(x,y)
    app.processEvents()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

### MAIN PROGRAM #####    
# this is a brutal infinite loop calling your realtime data plot
# make this interpret the incoming data
#Con()
#Communicate(1)
while True: update()


### END QtApp ####
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_() # you MUST put this at the end
##################
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I don't have an Arduino hooked up to grab data from so for this example I used random data to plot. When plotting data, you want to avoid using `time.sleep()` since it causes the GUI to freeze. Instead, use a `QtGui.QTimer()` connected to an update handler to plot data. Also as an optimization, you can use a thread to poll data and then update it in a separate timer.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
from threading import Thread
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import time

"""Scrolling Plot Widget Example"""

# Scrolling plot widget with adjustable X-axis and dynamic Y-axis
class ScrollingPlot(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollingPlot, self).__init__(parent)

        # Desired Frequency (Hz) = 1 / self.FREQUENCY
        # USE FOR TIME.SLEEP (s)
        self.FREQUENCY = .004

        # Frequency to update plot (ms)
        # USE FOR TIMER.TIMER (ms)
        self.TIMER_FREQUENCY = self.FREQUENCY * 1000

        # Set X Axis range. If desired is [-10,0] then set LEFT_X = -10 and RIGHT_X = 0
        self.LEFT_X = -10
        self.RIGHT_X = 0
        self.X_Axis = np.arange(self.LEFT_X, self.RIGHT_X, self.FREQUENCY)
        self.buffer = int((abs(self.LEFT_X) + abs(self.RIGHT_X))/self.FREQUENCY)
        self.data = [] 

        # Create Plot Widget 
        self.scrolling_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()

        # Enable/disable plot squeeze (Fixed axis movement)
        self.scrolling_plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.scrolling_plot_widget.setXRange(self.LEFT_X, self.RIGHT_X)
        self.scrolling_plot_widget.setTitle('Scrolling Plot Example')
        self.scrolling_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'Value')
        self.scrolling_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)')

        self.scrolling_plot = self.scrolling_plot_widget.plot()
        self.scrolling_plot.setPen(197,235,255)

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrolling_plot_widget)

        self.read_position_thread()
        self.start()

    # Update plot
    def start(self):
        self.position_update_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.position_update_timer.timeout.connect(self.plot_updater)
        self.position_update_timer.start(self.get_scrolling_plot_timer_frequency())

    # Read in data using a thread
    def read_position_thread(self):
        self.current_position_value = 0
        self.old_current_position_value = 0
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=())
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start()

    def read_position(self):
        frequency = self.get_scrolling_plot_frequency()
        while True:
            try:
                # Add data
                self.current_position_value = random.randint(1,101) 
                self.old_current_position_value = self.current_position_value
                time.sleep(frequency)
            except:
                self.current_position_value = self.old_current_position_value

    def plot_updater(self):
        self.dataPoint = float(self.current_position_value)

        if len(self.data) >= self.buffer:
            del self.data[:1]
        self.data.append(self.dataPoint)
        self.scrolling_plot.setData(self.X_Axis[len(self.X_Axis) - len(self.data):], self.data)

    def clear_scrolling_plot(self):
        self.data[:] = []

    def get_scrolling_plot_frequency(self):
        return self.FREQUENCY

    def get_scrolling_plot_timer_frequency(self):
        return self.TIMER_FREQUENCY

    def get_scrolling_plot_layout(self):
        return self.layout

    def get_current_position_value(self):
        return self.current_position_value

    def get_scrolling_plot_widget(self):
        return self.scrolling_plot_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plot Example')

    # Create scrolling plot
    scrolling_plot_widget = ScrollingPlot()

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Can use either to add plot to main layout
    #ml.addWidget(scrolling_plot_widget.get_scrolling_plot_widget(),0,0)
    ml.addLayout(scrolling_plot_widget.get_scrolling_plot_layout(),0,0)
    mw.show()

    # Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```